# Measuring Static Electricity

Tags: electricity

Is it possible to measure the static electricity in a room using a VOM or some other digital meter? I have a lot of static electricity building up in a carpeted room, and would rather not spend the money buying a meter to measure this.

Comment: This link http://amasci.com/emotor/voltmeas.html#volt5 tells you how to build a crude e-field sensor.  Static electricity is voltage without there necessarily being current present.  Several other detection methods are explained, also.

Comment: What are you hoping to learn from your measurement?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can build your own electrometer.

Take a look at this project:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-ElectrometerCapacitive-Object-Sensor/

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. The input impedance of most cheap meters is too low. So, you either need a specialist meter for numbers, or a cheap and easy way to detect the static field and give you an approximate idea. [This circuit](http://www.observationsblog.com/sciencetechnologyexperiments/-static-electricity-detector-easy-to-make), for example